# How to make a render_field submit button trigger a popover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, button

I have a form with a submit button. I am using flask forms therefore my html code for the button is:

```
{{ render_field(form.submit, class="btn btn-primary")}}
```

Thought my `__init__.py`, the button is supposed to lead to another page as in:

```
@user.route("/user/edit_package/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_package(id: int):
    form = PackageForm()
    permission_required(["User"])
    email = session["email"]
    user = User.select().where(User.email == email).first()
    p: Package = user.packages.where(Package.id == id).first()

if user and form.validate_on_submit():
    p.amount = form.amount.data
    p.category = form.category.data
    p.weight = form.weight.data
    p.size = form.size.data
    p.pkgType = form.pkg_type.data
    p.pkgSource = form.pkgSource.data
    p.pkgDes = form.pkgDes.data
    p.decription = form.description.data
    p.save()
    return redirect(url_for("user.packages"))
else:
    form.amount.data = p.amount
    form.category.data = p.category
    form.weight.data = p.weight
    form.size.data = p.size
    form.pkg_type.data = p.pkgType
    form.pkgSource.data = p.pkgSource
    form.pkgDes.data = p.pkgDes
    form.description.data = p.decription
return render_template("user/detailsupdate.html", form = form)
```

However, before the screen changes, I wish to display a pop-up for users to confirm that they wish to submit their form, which I need to trigger from the `render_field` button I posted above. Once the button on the pop up is clicked, then they should be taken to the next screen.

For this, I wish to use the bootstrap pop-up:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h5>Popover in a modal</h5>
  <p>This <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" title="Popover title" data-content="Popover body content is set in this attribute.">button</a> triggers a popover on click.</p>
  <hr>
  <h5>Tooltips in a modal</h5>
  <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">that link</a> have tooltips on hover.</p>
</div>
```

(I'll add my own details later)

How do I integrate the process? Where do I add this bootstrap pop-up code and how do I use the render_field submit button to trigger this pop up?